# How can I use a multiline value for an HTML tag attribute? (i.e. how do I escape newline?)

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, newline

How do I include a newline in an HTML tag attribute?

For example:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="javascript: foo('This is a multiline string.
This is the part after the newline.')">some link</a>
```

---

**Edit**: Sorry, bad example, what if the tag happened to not be in javascript, say:

```
<sometag someattr="This is a multiline string.
This is the part after the newline." />
```

---

**Edit 2**:  Turns out the newline in the string wasn't my problem, it was the javascript function I was calling.  FWIW, "`&#10;`" can be used for newline in an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From what I remember about the HTML standard, character entities work in attributes, so this *might* work:

```
<sometag someattr="This is a multiline string.&#10;This is the part after the newline." />
```

I'm not sure if the "newline" you want ought to be &#10; (\n) or &#13;&#10; (\r\n), and I'm not sure if browsers will interpret it the way you want.

Why do you need it?  What specific problem are you trying to solve by adding a newline in an HTML tag attribute?

Comment: The XML standard for attribute normalization is: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize

You have a good memory :-)

Comment: It's not working in my case. Why?

`<input type="text" name="email" value="Enter email here" title="First line sentence.&#10;Second line sentence.><br />`

Comment: @Baowen: you forgot to terminate your title attribute with a `"`.

Comment: @MariusGedminas Hi thanks, that too. But even after adding the ", it's still not working. I am trying to display those texts in a tooltip via  jQuery tooltip function.

Comment: @Bao newline in attributes aren't the same as newlines in the tool tip. A literally newline in HTML doesn't render as a newline

Comment: Great to find this here (and not at first there http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize). This is an important feature for MediaWiki extensions which often pipe arguments through attributes, for example `<youtube description"first paragraph&#10;second paragraph">...`

Answer (score 20):

To include a multiline value, just continue the text of the html attribute on the next line in your editor e.g.

```
<input type="submit" value="hallo
hallo">
```

will put the second hallo under the first

Comment: hmm... you're right.  the specific problem i was encountering was with the newline inside the javascript, but i assumed it extended to any html attribute in general but i guess i was mistaken. :-/

Comment: What if there are some blank lines in the value? like <iframe srcdoc='....'>.  I need put the whole html in the value string, I have to remove all the blank lines of it ?

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule newlines in attributes are preserved so your second example would work fine.  Did you try it?  Can you give a specific example where you are having problems with it?

As test take a look at this:-

```
<a href="somepage3.html" onclick="javascript: alert(this.getAttribute('thing'))" thing="This is a multiline string.
This is the part after the newline.">some link</a>
```

The alert include the newline in the attribute.

Comment: oops, turns out the problem was actually the javascript function i was calling, not the newline in the tag.

Comment: Just to clarify, newlines in attribute values ARE preserved,

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="javascript: foo('This is a multiline string. \
This is the part after the newline.')">some link</a>
```

Javascript needs a backslash at the end of the new line in a string.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not certain, but you can try \r or \n

```
javascript: foo('This is a multiline string.\rThis is the part after the newline.')
```

or

```
javascript: foo('This is a multiline string.\nThis is the part after the newline.')
```

Comment: What if it happened to not be within javascript?

Comment: are my examples not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, line breaks in HTML source code display what you intended in the result.

(Depends on the editor of course)

Answer (score -2):

Since it's in Javascript, you would use "\n" if inside double-quotes (not positive about single-quotes, I've been in PHP a lot lately.

Honestly, it's worth mentioning that you should use Events and a delegator instead of placing a javascript event directly on the element.